# QGIS: can't add themes

Tags: qgis

I have encountered a problem in one of my project and I don't know how or when this happened but I have noticed in the last week that I can no longer add themes. The Add Theme... menu option is greyed out. I have previously created 11 themes in this project, and was under the impression that you can create an unlimited number of themes. This does not occur in my other projects just this one. Had anyone else encountered this? Can anyone recommend a solution so I can add more themes?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add a theme if there is already a theme active.

In this case the "Add theme..." button will be greyed out and the "Rename Current Theme" button will be selectable:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the exact same problem and just now found a solution. You will have to add/remove a layer, or turn a current layer on/off and then QGIS will let you add another theme.

I assume it is thinking that because your current set up of layers is your theme, that you cannot add a new theme because it would be exactly the same as the current theme. Make any change to your layer list and it will let you add a new theme. I hope this helps because it was driving me crazy too.